# UiDocumentInteraction returns generic icons for images in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uidocumentinteraction

I need to make a simple file viewer and this method returns icon images for files.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageForFile:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    UIDocumentInteractionController *c = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    UIImage *thumbnail = nil;

    NSArray *icons = c.icons;
    if([icons count] > 0)
    {
        thumbnail = [icons objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return thumbnail;
}
```

On iPod icons are correct, but on iPad 1G it returns generic file icon for images (jpg/png/gif). Both have iOS 5.0. How can I get proper icons for images?

Thank you!